# Excel VBA filtering and grouping rows vba

Tags: excel, grouping, rows, vba

First of all, thanks in advance for your answers. I am working with Excel worksheets and vba and I have a problem.

I have this data (TABLE 1):

```
REFERENCE     COUNTRIES   ORIGIN   DISTRIBUTED
2014.AOK      Iran          1          0
2014.AOK      Bulgaria      0          1
2014.AOK      Spain         0          1
```

And I want to create a new sheet with the info structured as follows (TABLE 2):

```
REFERENCE    ORIGIN   DISTRIBUTED
2014.AOK      Iran    Bulgaria, Spain
```

As you can see on table 1, Reference is the same for the 3 rows. Each row has a different country. My aim is to write all the info in just 1 row, depending on "DISTRIBUTED".

- If a country has a 1 in DISTRIBUTED Column, then it should be added after the last one which had 1 in that column. In this example Bulgaria and Spain should be together in the same column, separated by a comma.

I have tried to do this using vba, but I have no idea how to do it. Could you give me a clue?

Thank you very very very much!!

Comment: What about using a pivot table?

Comment: I don't know if it could work. I obtain this kind of data by opening an XML file. This action is a part of a big macro I am developing.
But I will take your idea into account. Thanks mate :)

Comment: Are `ORIGIN` and `DISTRIBUTED` mutually exclusive? Is the `ORIGIN` a single value for each `REFERENCE`?

Comment: `I have tried to do this using VBA`... what have you tried?  VBA will work for this.  You can use a `Dictionary` or the `AutoFilter` to go through each unique entry in `REFERENCE`.  The filter is better because then you just iterate visible cells `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and check the value in `ORIGIN` or `DIST` to output to the right column.  The `&` operator or `Join` function will generate the list.

Comment: ORIGIN is single, I haven't seen cases with more than one ORIGIN.
Byron, I tried to work with AutoFilters but I did not make it. I will try what you've told me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one off excercise then I would use formula in the worksheet as that would be quickest to create, however if you need reusable VBA code then i would work with the data in an array, something like this:

```
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim avArray As Variant
Dim rngOriginal As Range, rngExpanded As Range

'get the range of the original table of data
Set rngOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'increase the range by the number of output columns we require, 3 in this case, then dump into array
Set rngExpanded = Range(rngOriginal.Resize(rngOriginal.Rows.Count, rngOriginal.Columns.Count + 3).Address)
avArray = rngExpanded.Value

'loop though the rows ignoring the first row (headers)
For i = (LBound(avArray, 1) + 1) To UBound(avArray, 1)
    If avArray(i, 3) = 1 Then 'if origin then
        k = i 'remember row
        avArray(i, 5) = avArray(i, 1) 'output reference
        avArray(i, 6) = avArray(i, 2) 'output origin country
    End If
    If avArray(i, 4) = 1 Then 'if distributed then
        If avArray(k, 7) = vbNullString Then 'if first distributed
            avArray(k, 7) = avArray(i, 2) 'then just assign country
        Else
            avArray(k, 7) = Join(Array(avArray(k, 7), avArray(i, 2)), ",") 'else join to existing countries
        End If
    End If
Next

'dump array back to sheet
rngExpanded.Value = avArray
```

This particular solution requires that the data has been sorted suitably first, i.e. by reference, then by origin, then by distributed.

This code will put the output data in the 3 columns next to the original data.  You could change it so that the original data is replaced by the output data but thats up to you.

Comment: Thanks mate! :) I read your code and start working with it. I finally made it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
It doesn't, but it should. May help others though.

```
Sub ert()
e = NamesArrayFiltered(Range("B:B"), Range("D:D"), 1, Range("A:A"), "2014.AOK")
MsgBox e
End Sub
```

'

```
Public Function NamesArrayFiltered(myNames As Range, Optional Filter1 As Range, Optional FilterCriterion1 As Variant, _
                                   Optional Filter2 As Range, Optional FilterCriterion2 As Variant) As String
NamesArrayFiltered = ""
Dim FilterFound(1 To 2) As Boolean
    FilterFound(1) = Not Filter1 Is Nothing
        If FilterFound(1) Then FilterFound(1) = Not Filter1 Is Nothing
    FilterFound(2) = Not Filter2 Is Nothing
        If FilterFound(2) Then FilterFound(2) = Not Filter2 Is Nothing
Set Filter1 = Intersect(Filter1, Filter1.Worksheet.UsedRange)
Set myNames = Intersect(myNames, myNames.Worksheet.UsedRange)
Set Filter2 = Intersect(Filter1, Filter1.Worksheet.UsedRange)

Dim RowsCount As Long, ColumnsCount As Long, CellsCount As Long
RowsCount = Filter1.Rows.Count
ColumnsCount = Filter1.Columns.Count
CellsCount = Filter1.Cells.Count
Dim NamesArray() As Variant, Counter1 As Long
ReDim NamesArray(1 To CellsCount)
Counter1 = 1

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To RowsCount
    For j = 1 To ColumnsCount
        If FilterFound(1) Then
            If Filter1(i, j).Value2 = FilterCriterion1 Then
                If FilterFound(2) Then
                    If Filter2(i, j).Value2 = FilterCriterion2 Then
                        NamesArray(Counter1) = myNames(i, j).Value2
                        Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
                    End If
                Else
                    NamesArray(Counter1) = myNames(i, j).Value2
                    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
            'If (Filter1(i, j).Value2 = FilterCriterion1 And FilterFound(1)) And (Filter1(i, j).Value2 = FilterCriterion1 And FilterFound(1)) Then
            '    NamesArray(Counter1) = myNames(i, j).Value2
            '    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
            'End If
    Next j
Next i
NamesArrayFiltered = Join(NamesArray(), ", ")
NamesArrayFiltered = Left(NamesArrayFiltered, InStr(NamesArrayFiltered, ", , ") - 1)
End Function
```